# PostgreSQL query to get the current password

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query which should result me the following details:

Host,
Port,
Username,
Password.

Comment: I think you might not get password but host and username by `select * from mysql.user;` and port by `show variables like "%port%";`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the login user and the currently active role with

```
SELECT session_user, current_user;
```

You can get the client address and port with

```
SELECT client_addr, client_port
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

You can get the server port with

```
SHOW port;
```

There is no way to find out the server address with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the server address of the current connection with `inet_server_addr()` and the port with `inet_server_port()` (but not all addresses and ports the server listens on). The current user can be obtained with `current_user` (or `session_user`, if you want to get the session user). (See ["9.25. System Information Functions"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-info.html))

The passwords are in `pg_catalog.pg_authid.rolpassword`. But an ordinary user might not have the permission to query `pg_catalog.pg_authid`. And even if they do, the passwords are most likely MD5 hashed and that's irreversible. (See ["50.8. `pg_authid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-authid.html))

But if you got a lot (really a lot!) of time at hand, you might want to try a brute force attack on the password hash with a recursive CTE.

All that leads to something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE c(c)
AS
(
SELECT chr(s.i) c FROM generate_series(97, 122) s(i)
UNION ALL
SELECT concat(c.c, chr(s.i))
       FROM c
            CROSS JOIN generate_series(97, 122) s(i)
       WHERE length(concat(c.c, chr(s.i))) <= 4
)
SELECT inet_server_addr() "host",
       inet_server_port() "port",
       current_user "username",
       c.c "password"
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_authid pgai
            INNER JOIN c c
                       ON pgai.rolpassword = concat('md5', md5(concat(c.c, current_user)))
                          AND pgai.rolname = current_user;
```

Change the maximum length of the generated words and the used characters to what you want to try. This example uses all lower case letters and words up to a length of 4.

(But note, that you should take this more as a joke. It's fun to think about how to do something like this in SQL. However, for a good password, using all printables and being of sufficient length, you most certainly don't want to wait for the query to end. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can not show your current password.

To show the current user, the server host and the port use:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER, inet_server_addr( ), inet_server_port() port;
```